# Makes pointer from integer without a cast in C function calls

Tags: c

So I am really confused with this after fiddling around with it for the past hour.

I am trying to call a function within another function within another function. I am getting an error message saying: "passing argument 1 of displayDeck makes pointer from integer without a cast. Expected int * but argument is of type int."

```
void printCard(int card)
{
    char ranks[RANKS] = {'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','J','Q','K'};
    char *suits = "SHDC";

    printf("%c%c", ranks[card%RANKS], suits[card/RANKS]);
}

void displayDeck(int deck[])
{
    int count = 0;
    int cleanDisplay = 0;

    while(count < MAXIMUM) 
    {
        if(cleanDisplay == RANKS)
        {
            printf("\n");
            cleanDisplay = 0;
        }
        printCard(deck[count]);
        printf(" ");
        cleanDisplay++;
        count++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

void dealCards(int deck[], int hands, int cards)
{
    int total = hands * cards;
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;

    while(counter < total)
    {
        if(counter2 == cards)
        {
            printf("\nPlayer's Hand: \n");
            counter2 = 0;
        }
        displayDeck(deck[counter]);
        counter2++;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

displayDeck is accepting an int, and so is my call to it in the dealCards function. So I am not sure what to do here. I may have to implement another pointer? I am trying to deal out cards from an array that I have created and shuffled.

I am guessing the error is somewhere within printCard, since that's the only function dealing with pointers.

P.S I am still rather new to C so if this is some type of simple error than apologies.

Answer (score 1):

you have a function `void displayDeck(int deck[])` which accepts an array, which is expecting a pointer to the first element of an array.

then you give it `displayDeck(deck[counter]);` which is a single `int`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, defining the paramter as

```
void displayDeck(int deck[])
```

and

```
void dealCards(int deck[], int hands, int cards)
```

isn't good c code sytle, try make that

```
void displayDeck(int *deck)
```

and

```
void dealCards(int *deck, int hands, int cards)
```

and replace this call

```
displayDeck(deck[counter]);
```

with

```
displayDeck(deck);
```

because you want the whole array not just the int value at deck[counter].